# Installing only a certain subpackage from src.RPM, Raspbian

Tags: rpm, raspbian, selinux, source

Attempting to install `setroubleshoot-server` from source, as there are no ARM71 packages(error recieved from Alien rpm package installer when using arm7hl).

Default compilation from an extracted `src.rpm` installs the entire desktop package, which takes up alot of disk space with many desktop dependencies. Since I'm not running a desktop, and it wouldn't be feasible to do so with my hardware, I need only the `setroubleshoot-server` package for it's commandline tools.

On the fedora repository, there are several sub RPMs and and the main RPM. The source RPM installs the primary package from what I can tell, which is the desktop version.

How would I install only the `setroubleshoot-server` package from the given `src.rpm` file in the repository?

Said files: 
http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=783614

Raspberry Pi 3, lightweight raspbian.
SELINUX is working with custom kernel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* modify the spec-file to eliminate the (unnamed) main package and then make the rules for the server subpackage become the actual target.  You can see the relevant parts by just looking at the lines beginning with '%', e.g.,

```
%find_lang %{name}
%package server
%description server
%pre server
%post server
%systemd_post auditd.service
%postun server
%systemd_postun_with_restart auditd.service
%triggerun server -- %{name}-server < 3.2.24-4
%clean
%files server -f %{name}.lang
```

which have "server" as a parameter.

But if you're not used to writing spec-files that could take a while.

Aside from that, no: there is no direct way to build just *part* of a package.

Further reading:

- [Can rpmbuild command build only 1 subpackage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727461/can-rpmbuild-command-build-only-1-subpackage)
- [How do I make rpmbuild only build subpackages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22574102/how-do-i-make-rpmbuild-only-build-subpackages)
- [Re: How to prevent rpmbuild from building %package subpackages?](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2007-April/msg00034.html)